# load yago files into MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I want to load the files of Yago database into my database in mysql. I tryed what is written in yago's website (to run the script Postgres.sql) but since I work on windows it does not recognize the "psql" operation. I tryed also to open the script directly in mysql but it says that there is sql syntax. What can I do? Thanks for helpers!

Comment: "*but since I work on windows it does not recognize the "psql" operation*" - Postgres is also available on Windows. But I don't understand why you would want to use the Postgres command line client to load something into MySQL?

Comment: this is what is written in yago's website. How can I load yago into MySql?

Comment: May i suggest you post your message in the 'Yago' forum. As interesting as it looks as 'software', i suspect the expertise / interest here is limited. Now, this comment may turn into a 'honeypot' so expect the unexpected soon - or not! :-)

Comment: [Yago appears to be some kind of dataset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGO_(database)). It's available in a bunch of formats, so if you want to use it with MySQL, why are you trying to work with a PostgreSQL dump?

Comment: I thought the script would work on mysql. I was wrong. any idea how can I convert the information on yago to mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load a Postgres SQL script into a mySQL database.

Postgres and mySQL speak different dialects of SQL and can't necessarily understand scripts meant for eachother.

If you want to load up a postgres SQL script, use a postgres database. 
Installers for the windows version of postgres are available here:
https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Once you have postgres installed, you can then use an admin tool e.g. 
PGadmin (https://www.pgadmin.org/) to run the script on your DB and import the information within.

Feel free to comment if you want more detailed instructions.